# Add custom bulk actions to admin orders list in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, woocommerce, backend, bulk, orders

In Woocommerce backend *(admin)*, I have a function that allows the shop-manager to download all orders between two dates with a specific bunch of required data:

```
function write_to_file($date_initial, $date_final) {
    global $attach_download_dir, $attach_download_file;

    // Opens/creates file
    $myfile = fopen($attach_download_dir . '/' . $attach_download_file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    // Populates first line
    fwrite($myfile, 'Date; Parent Order ID; Order ID' . PHP_EOL);

    // Retrieves orders data
    if ( isset($date_initial) && isset($date_final) ) $args = array( 'date_created' => $date_initial . '...' . $date_final );
    if ( isset($date_initial) && empty($date_final) ) $args = array( 'date_created' => '>=' . $date_initial );
    if ( empty($date_initial) && isset($date_final) ) $args = array( 'date_created' => '<=' . $date_final );
    if ( empty($date_initial) && empty($date_final) ) $args = array( );
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    // Populates file with orders data
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $order_data = $order->get_data();
        fwrite($myfile,
            // Date of order creation
            $order_data['date_created']->date('d/M/Y') . '; ' .

            // Parent Order ID
            '#' . ( ( $order->get_type() === 'shop_order' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->get_parent_id() ) . '; ' .

            // Order ID
            '#' . $order->get_id()
        )
    }
}
```

This function is triggered on a button click…

I would like To enable something similar from admin orders list bulk selection functionality. So the selected orders by shop manager on admin orders list *(see the screenshot below)* will be sent to a similar custom script and then downloaded.

In that case, the selected orders would override the specified dates, if any, in the orders retrieval.

[image]

However, I can't find a variable to access that tells me which orders are selected at that moment by the admin user.

Any help will be appreciated…

Comment: Yes, its missing there ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the complete way to make your functionality work on bulk order list action selection, instead of date range:

```
// Adding to admin order list bulk dropdown a custom action 'custom_downloads'
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'downloads_bulk_actions_edit_product', 20, 1 );
function downloads_bulk_actions_edit_product( $actions ) {
    $actions['write_downloads'] = __( 'Download orders', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

// Make the action from selected orders
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'downloads_handle_bulk_action_edit_shop_order', 10, 3 );
function downloads_handle_bulk_action_edit_shop_order( $redirect_to, $action, $post_ids ) {
    if ( $action !== 'write_downloads' )
        return $redirect_to; // Exit

    global $attach_download_dir, $attach_download_file; // ???

    $processed_ids = array();

    foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
        $order_data = $order->get_data();

        // Your code to be executed on each selected order
        fwrite($myfile,
            $order_data['date_created']->date('d/M/Y') . '; ' .
            '#' . ( ( $order->get_type() === 'shop_order' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->get_parent_id() ) . '; ' .
            '#' . $order->get_id()
        );
        $processed_ids[] = $post_id;
    }

    return $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array(
        'write_downloads' => '1',
        'processed_count' => count( $processed_ids ),
        'processed_ids' => implode( ',', $processed_ids ),
    ), $redirect_to );
}

// The results notice from bulk action on orders
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'downloads_bulk_action_admin_notice' );
function downloads_bulk_action_admin_notice() {
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['write_downloads'] ) ) return; // Exit

    $count = intval( $_REQUEST['processed_count'] );

    printf( '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>' .
        _n( 'Processed %s Order for downloads.',
        'Processed %s Orders for downloads.',
        $count,
        'write_downloads'
    ) . '</p></div>', $count );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

In the returned url I have something like (for 2 selected / processed orders):
`wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order&paged=1&write_downloads=1&processed_count=2&processed_ids=847%2C846`

I can't test your included script but it's the way to do it on Woocommerce Orders Admin list.

---

**VARIABLES:**

The available variables are set by `add_query_arg()` function as you will see. When the action is triggered, you get those variables in the URL through GET method…

You can set any variable yourself too…

In this example you can use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` with:

- `$_GET['write_downloads']` *(the **name action**: `true` or `false`)*
- `$_GET['processed_count']` *(the **number of selected orders**)*
- `$_GET['processed_ids']` *(the **Order Ids** separated by an url-encoded coma `%2C`)*

> So you can either execute your script:
>
> - **inside** my code function (like in my code) … or …
> - **outside** it, using the available variables once the action is triggered…

---

#### To remove a specific action from the dropdown orders bulk actions

For example we want to remove **"On hold"** status change:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'remove_a_bulk_order_action', 20, 1 );
function remove_a_bulk_order_action( $actions ) {
    unset($actions['mark_on-hold']);

    return $actions;
}
```

> All statuses change keys start with `mark_` + the status slug *(without `wc-`)*.

Comment: I tried your code but it leads me to a white page. Do you have any idea why this is the case? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698040/how-to-setup-a-bulk-action-in-the-woocommerce-order-list?noredirect=1#comment124989363_70698040

Comment: The answer has a PHP error. In function `downloads_handle_bulk_action_edit_shop_order()` $myfile variable is not defined as it is in the OP. Copy the line which assigns $myfile from OP to fix.

Comment: insert on the 15th line the following:
`// Opens/creates file`
`$myfile = fopen($attach_download_dir . '/' . $attach_download_file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");`
and:
`//Populate first Line`
`fwrite($myfile, 'Date; Parent Order ID; Order ID' . PHP_EOL);`
Please note that I added the comments as well. These are 4 lines you need to import including comments.

Comment: how about the current bulk actions in  order list, for example "move to trash". Does `handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` filter work on it?

Comment: Use `unset($actions['trash']);`