# Send selected order notification emails from admin list in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

Would it be possible to add a custom bulk action to orders list in Woocommerce, which would allow for sending of order emails, based on the orders selected in the list? I have found very useful posts here (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562272/add-custom-bulk-actions-to-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce-3)), describing the procedure to make custom bulk actions, but I am missing the final piece of the puzzle - how to make that custom bulk action send out order notification emails.

I have looked through numerous plugins, but I haven't found anything related to my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the link you supplied you will need to use `wp_mail()` function in the `foreach` loop.

This will send an email to each order in the loop.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/