# How to add a bulk action to the admin order list when another filter is already being added?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to write some orderdata to a custom database using a bulk action.  Now I know how to write to a database but I can't seem to get the bulk action to work. I wrote the following:

```
<?php    
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'doa_bulk_actions_collect_products', 20, 1 );
function doa_bulk_actions_collect_products( $actions ) {
    $actions['doa-collect-orders'] = __( 'Verzamel producten', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'doa_handle_bulk_action_collect_products', 10, 3 );
function doa_handle_bulk_action_collect_products( $redirect_to, $action, $post_ids ) {
    if ( $action !== 'doa-collect-orders' ) {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
    //write to database
    return $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array( 'doa_collect_orders' => 'thisisatest' ), $redirect_to );

}
?>
```

According to my knowledge this should work fine. But when I use the action I get a white page. On the following URL:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=shop_order&_wpnonce=cb753a3863&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fpost_type%3Dshop_order&action=doa-collect-orders&m=0&deliveryDate=&_customer_user=&paged=1&post%5B%5D=204576&action2=doa-collect-orders
```

Now after some more testing, I found out that another plugin is using this same filter but somehow that is messing up.

Now this plugin is build in a different programming style:

```
class WCDN_Writepanel {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // Load the hooks.
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'load_admin_hooks' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Load the admin hooks
     */
    public function load_admin_hooks() {
        // Removing the following hook will make my code work:
        add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', array( $this, 'my_bulk_action_handler' ), 10, 3 );
    }
}
```

Now for some reason this is already enough to break everything. Even after removing everything from the filter I still get a white screen. Only removing the actual `add_filter` will make my code work. What is going on?

Comment: Where are the orderIDs passed to which the action should be applied? as is the case, in the code you refer to

Comment: @7uc1f3r, I don't think I completely understand your question. The filter `handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` should contain three variables of which the first should contain an array of the selected orders.

Comment: What's happening behind the scenes on the basis of doa_collect_orders being set? I've pasted your code into a fresh copy of WP with WooCommerce installed and running the bulk action on a couple of posts redirects back to /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order&paged=1&doa_collect_orders=thisisatest with no white page.

Comment: @TimSheehan, thank you for your reply, it turns out a fresh copy indeed solves the problem. I looked into my plugins and found that another plugin is using the same filter and somehow breaks my code. I have changed my question accordingly.

Comment: Where is the code for the `my_bulk_action_handler()` method in the `WCDN_Writepanel` class?

Comment: Can you try changing the priority of your filter that is used in common with the plugin, so that it runs after the plugin ie change
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'doa_handle_bulk_action_collect_products', 10, 3 );
to say
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'doa_handle_bulk_action_collect_products', 15, 3 );

Comment: The priority of the filter cannot be changed. For some reason you will be redirected to a different page. It turns out mid way the other plugin the function was returned without the redirection url. I will delete the question shortly as the question doesn't have much value now. Thank you all for the help!